# Angular JS embedding a html page as a widget

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to learn `Angular js`. 
I want to embed another website `as a part of my webpage`; inside a "`div`".
I have the following code so far which does that for me.

However, the embedded website will have hyperlinks in it. When someone clicks on the hyperlinks,is there a way where the new contents are displayed inside the same `div`?

> Is it possible?

---

```
<body ng-app="sampleApp">
    <div ng-controller="CommonController">
        <div>
            <a href="#" ng-click="show()">ShowPage</a>
        </div>
            <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="expression"/>
    </div>
    <script
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);
        sampleApp
                .controller(
                        'CommonController',
                        function($scope, $http) {
                            $scope.show = function() {
                                var responsePromise = $http
                                        .get("http://localhost:8080/HelpDynamic/spring/welcome");
                                responsePromise.success(function(data, status,
                                        headers, config) {
                                    $scope.expression = data;
                                });
                                responsePromise.error(function(data, status,
                                        headers, config) {
                                    alert("AJAX failed!");
                                });
                            }
                        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is by using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) instead of `ng-router`. This community built module allow you to use nested views. It means that you can integrate other templates inside the one you use.

To see how to do it, I recommend that you read its well-written guide about nested views : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am +1 ing you for now. I will read the link and try to incorporate tomorrow. Will let you know if any issues or accept the answer.